# How to wait for async subscribe to full fill a global variable?

Tags: angular, firebase, asynchronous, angularfire

I have an async firebase call similar to:

```
this.fbProvider.fbGetProfile()
               .subscribe(p => {                                       
                            this.profile = p;
                         });
```

...but then I need to use `this.profile` in others function like...

```
console.log(this.profile.email);
```

...and it keeps returning an error:

> Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

any idea how I could wait for the subscribe to full fill my local variable before I need to use it?

ps: my problem is bigger than that and solutions such as using `.then()` makes my code a mess. I tried something with `await`, but it did not work out as well.

`

Comment: In case of down voting on my question, please explain why so I can improve it and also learn with it.

Comment: A fallback to promises often occurs because of misunderstanding of how observables work. You have XY problem. if you need this result in other functions, than you need to subscribe to this stream in these functions, not in this place.

Comment: @estus, sorry about it, but I did not get it. You saying that 'subscribes' return 'observables' and 'then' return 'promises'? and those two would require a different thing?

Comment: `subscribe` returns a subscription, and it's done too early in the code above. `subscribe` should be done in the point where an observable is consumed (where `profile` is really needed), otherwise a stream should be merged/modified with RxJS operators. Promises and observables have something in common and sometimes are interchangeable, but they result in different coding habits when being used correctly.

Comment: @estus, would you have any content where I could study more about both 'coding habits'?

Comment: I've seen no good articles on promises vs observables. The habits result from RxJS API and capabilities. `subscribe`, `map`, `mergeMap` or`switchMap` can be appropriate depending on the case, while it would be same `then` in promises. I'd suggest to start with generic learning materials, Egghead RxJS course and https://www.learnrxjs.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `async` / `await` with promise and resolve that once the api call completes:

```
await new Promise(resolve => {
    this.fbProvider.fbGetProfile()
           .subscribe(p => {                                       
                        this.profile = p;
                        resolve();
                     });
});
```

Remember to put `async` before the function where you use this code.

Comment: There's already toPromise operator. The wheel is being reinvented, and not in the correct way. An error will result in pending promise.

Answer (score 0):

```
  async uploadToStorage(element) {
    var imgUrl = "";
    var uploadTask = this.gallery_ref.child('Gallery/' + element.name).put(element);
    // Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.

    await new Promise(resolve => {

      uploadTask.on('state_changed', snapshot => {
        // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
        var progress = (uploadTask.snapshot.bytesTransferred / uploadTask.snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
        }
      }, error => {

      }, function () {
        // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
        uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function (downloadURL) {
          imgUrl = downloadURL;
          console.log("url");
          console.log(imgUrl);
          resolve();
        });
      });
    })
    return imgUrl
  }
```

This is a firebase function which is used to track the state change of a file uploading to firebase storage. Using "await" as given in the above answer, worked for me!